# Default answer will take [ENTER] rather than mouse click

Tags: feature-request

This may be way too trivial but I was wondering if it is possible to make the default answer (EG "Vote to close" etc.) accept the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key as well as a mouse click? That would make things so much nicer.

Comment: This makes sense; Esc already closes the dialog. Note that if you *start* the dialog with keyboard shortcuts it will work (m -> c -> number -> another number if you need a suboption -> enter). Type a question mark to see which shortcuts are available.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, how do you *start* the dialog with the keyboard? I have to **click** on "close" or "flag" to get the dialog.

Comment: You can just press 'm', this will select the post (it will get a gray background), and then press 'c'. I forgot to tell you that you need to enable the feature in your settings: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237166/295232

Comment: Cool, thx for the tip on shortcuts, I'll try them out! But it does not seem to work when reviewing questions and answers in the review queues, but I will hammer on it a bit more in case I am doing something wrong (HAH!)